# The difference between mean squared error of train data and test data is very large

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression, tensor

i used linear regression to make ML model but met problem.
this is my result values

Model1 Training Mean squared error: `154.96`

Model1 Test Mean squared error: `72018955075415565139968.00`

training score: `0.48`

testing score: `-236446352571492139008.00`

i dont know why these values are printed
because overfitting?

i am using `tensorflow 1.13.1` and `python 3.7`

Comment: This is most likely a bug in your data processing. Can you give us some more information on what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please add the code's calculation of MSE to the question.

Comment: How did you create Train and Test datasets? This type of issues can arise if it is not a random split. Try shuffling the dataset before splitting into Train and Test

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the case of `Overfitting`.

You can

- Ensure that you are following the Data Pre-Processing Steps like 1. `Missing Value Imputation` 2. `Fixing the Outliers` 3. `Scaling` or `Normalizing` the Features
- Ensure that you are Performing `Feature Engineering` (removing undesired Features, adding meaningful Features)
- `Shuffle` the Data, by using `shuffle=True` in `model.fit`. Code is shown below:

`history = cnn_model.fit(x = X_train_reshaped,
                            y = y_train,
                            batch_size = 512,
                            epochs = epochs, callbacks=[callback],
                            verbose = 1, validation_data = (X_test_reshaped, y_test),
                            validation_steps = 10, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, 
                            shuffle = True)`

- Use `Early Stopping`. Code is shown below

  `callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=15)`
- Use `Dropout`
- Use `Regularization`. Code for `Regularization` is shown below (You can try `l1 Regularization` or `l1_l2 Regularization` as well):

`
    from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2

```
Regularizer = l2(0.001)

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    units = 64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=Regularizer, bias_regularizer=Regularizer,
    activity_regularizer=Regularizer))

tf.keras.layers(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Dense(units = 10, activation = 'sigmoid', 
                        activity_regularizer=Regularizer, kernel_regularizer=Regularizer))`
```

- Last but not the least, Try removing some `Layers`, as it reduces the number of Trainable Parameters

If your `Test Accuracy` and `Testing Score` doesn't improve despite following above instructions, please share the complete code so that we can help you.

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!